# Handling image size based on different ios device versions (Unity2D)

Tags: c#, unity, ios

This game is built using Unity 4, C#, and the 2D toolkit. In the unity game scene settings, it is set to (ios 5 tall) and I matched the Menu background dimensions with the dimensions of an ios 5 tall device.  When testing this build on a different ios device(ios 4 etc...), the menu background doesn't fit (stretch) to the width and height of the tested device's dimensions. The answer seems pretty obvious that i'm not handling all devices dimensions.

What would be a good approach on handling images based on different ios devices? Are there any build settings to build a project that handles each device dimensions?

Thanks in advance for any advice or a good approach for cross-device handling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to figure out which device the app is running on have a look at:

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/iPhone-generation.html function
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/iPhoneGeneration.html enumeration list

example here: http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/iphone-generation.32742/

Comment: Awesome. This is half of what I was looking for! So let's say i'm using a  background gui sprite that is going to switch images based on the device. Would I then write this script similar to above and then attach it to the background gui? Is this common for handling cross devices? This way i'm going to have to attach this script to every sprite. Will this cause issues? Or is there a more efficient way to load all images with one script instead of tons.

Comment: had a bit of a google and I think these might be of interest:  http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/79546/how-do-you-handle-aspect-ratio-differences-with-unity-2d http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21369067/how-to-work-with-different-screen-resolutions unfortunately it looks like a "it depends" question.

Comment: Thank you. I also found similar answers and it definitely depends on the goal at hand. The first links were what I was looking for to get started. Thanks!