# How can I get Unity to do letterbox/pillarbox to maintain aspect ratio?

Tags: unity, aspect-ratio

I'd like my game to have the same aspect ratio *at all cost*, including keeping all UI elements fixed in the same place. I'm totally ok with losing screen space in the interest of fixing the aspect ratio.

Comment: If you need this to work on non-UI elements too, you can use the [camera letterboxing/pillarboxing script described in this answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/144578/39518).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, attach a `Canvas Scaler` component to the `GameObject` with your `Canvas` on it. Set it to `Scale With Screen Size`. Set the resolution you want your game to mimic. I have 640x1136 set. Set `Screen Match Mode` to `Expand`.

[image]

Inside this `GameObject`, create a new one. In my scene, it's called "GameSizingPanel". You can see it just has a `CanvasRenderer` and an `Aspect Ratio Fitter`. Divide the width by the height that you set in the outer object. In my case, 640 / 1136 is 0.56338. Set this number in the `Aspect Ratio` slot. Set the `Aspect Mode` to `Fit In Parent`.

Attach all of your game objects to be displayed under the object with the `Aspect Ratio Fitter` in it.

[image]

If you'd like to see what the results are like, you can download the (free) finished product on iOS or Android. It's called "Cognizer". There's also a web version at my website, which you can find in my profile.