# Better way to implement iPhone Games targeting iPhone 4, 4S & 5

Tags: graphics, iphone

**iPhone 5:**

- 4″ at 1146 x 640 resolution retina display

**iPhone 4, 4S:**

- 3.5″ at 960 x 640 resolution retina display

We are developing games targeting iPhone 4, 4S & 5.

- What graphics resource ratio would be better with less time and
  investment?
- Which ratio would be easy to integrate with targeting device with
  less coding?

Comment: A [very similar question](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/51/how-can-i-develop-my-android-game-for-different-phone-resolutions) has been asked for Android; please take a look at those answers for additional tips. And for even more information, on that question look at the "Linked" and "Related" sidebar sections on the right side of the page for several more questions that might provide further information.

Comment: @Ricket, Yes, good resource. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is : depends on the type of the game.

For example, if the game is a racing 3D game, you can modify the aspect ratio of the screen, but all the assets stay the same. If it's a board game with zoom - the same applies - you will just see more of the board.

The main problem will be, IMHO, GUI. Note however, that in some type of games it would be perfectly ok to leave it exactly as-is; it would make steering with on-screen controls easier, while keeping the gui visible.

As the footnote: iPhone 5 has the same horizontal resulotion as 4S. Whilst you can just play 4S games on 5 in letterbox mode, opposite isn't possible. The letterbox space can be filled not only with extending of the game display, but, as I mentioned earlier, larger gui or controls

Comment: Any specific guideline?

Comment: I don't think I can help more