# ios screen design -> how to target multiple devices

Tags: ios, art, screen

I am writing an IOS Game, landscape only and I am having a conceptual issue with my artwork. The screens are all different sizes. Retina, non-retina as well.

Non Retina ipads + ipad mini is 1024 x 768.

Retina ipads are 2048 x 1536.

So how big do I draw my art? What concept am I messing up? Any screen templates I can download to help me. i.e, learn the boundaries, etc?

Comment: There are lots of questions on the site about resolution independence.  Like this one http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/34/how-do-you-approach-resolution-independence-in-raster-based-graphics-content?lq=1

Answer (score 1):

Generally you should create your art for the highest-resolution you're planning to support and then scale it down (there are tools out there that do this automatically).

That eliminates the resolution-problem and leaves you with the problem of the *aspect-ratio*. There's no  definitive solution to this problem, you'll have to figure out what works best for your game (scaling/cropping, letterboxing etc.). Here's a [similar question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/51/how-can-i-develop-my-android-game-for-different-phone-resolutions).

When your screen-sizes have significant differences in size (eg. a desktop-computer vs. a smartphone), then you'll have to adapt your design to these different sizes. Text that's perfectly readable on a big screen might become unreadable on a mobile-device. On the other hand a HUD/GUI of a mobile-screen applied to a large screen might look clunky and not appropriate for the device.

Please note that I'm talking about physical-size and not resolution here. I'm aware that a iPad 4 has a higher resolution than most desktop-computer monitors, but these pixels are so dense, that you still design your layout for 1024x768.